# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: json, wcf, twitter

I have a WCF service using a webHttpBinding that is returning JSON. The service makes a request to the Twitter API ver 1.1 to get tweets. The service works fine on my local machine and on our production machine, but I get this error on our DEV machine.

**"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."**

- The Web.Config files are identical (other than values ie connection strings etc)
- The code on each server is the same.
- I've verified that both servers have the same anti-virus running, and it's up to date.
- I've checked all IIS settings and they're the same and both servers
- I increased the maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferSize values in the webHttpBinding
- I increased the maxItemsInObjectGraph value in the dataContractSerializer
- I increased the service's timeout value
- I added the service to another site on the DEV server and it returns the same error
- I've read every post on StackOverflow related to this error but had no luck

This leads me to believe that something on the DEV *machine* is causing this error, but I'm not sure what. What am I missing? Is there a server setting that could cause this error?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Things I would check are OS (32 bit vs 64 bit, though that wouldn't strike me as the most likely culprit) or network connectivity for the dev machine.  I would also suggest enabling WCF tracing on the dev machine (if you haven't already), and taking a peak at the event logs might show something as well.  Tracing is probably the best bet overall.

Comment: You can use Fiddler to debug the traffic and see what Twitter is sending back to you. Also, if your server clock is out of sync with Twitter, your authorization will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. This issue was caused by some filtering done by our server admin. Since we don't filter traffic on our DEV server, I wasn't having any issues.